# How do I change the layout and style of a contribution page displayed on a wordpress website?

Tags: contribution-page, css

I've got premium options included which display as toggle framed text and not with tick boxes (which I want) and it's using Times as the default font (which I don't want). Also, I need the Profile section (name, address etc) to be at the top of the page, not the bottom. Any pointers?

Comment: Are you asking about CSS? Or how to put CSS on the page?  The former is outside the scope of this Stack Exchange, but the latter isn't.  However, the easiest methods depend on your CMS; could you please edit your question to indicate whether you're on WordPress, Drupal, etc.?

Comment: Title says WP - was maybe added after your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest option for you would be to use Caldera forms plugin with the CiviCRM connectors. That way you could style your caldera forms to your needs and still have the submission into CiviCRM